# IF command & Dates

Tags: excel

What formula can I use in Excel to give me a type of warning when a product date will expire. For instance in cell A1 is a formula for today date. In B1 will be the date when the product expires. I would like to know in cell C1, a week before the expire date that the product is going to expire.

Comment: `=IF(DAYS(B1,A1) <= 7, "EXPIRING", "")`

Comment: @AlexK., this is an answer. Please post it as such so it can be upvoted and accepted.